# Using JDBC inside Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-phoenix, hdp

I wrote a Spark application for bulk-loading a Phoenix Table. Everything worked for a few weeks now, but for a few days I get some Problems with duplicated rows. This was caused by faulty table stats. However, a possible Workaround for that would be to delete and re-generate the stats for this table.

Therefore I Need to open a JDBC Connection to my Phoenix database and call the Statements for deleting and creating the stats.

Since I Need to do this after iserting the new data via Spark, I also want to create and use this JDBC Connection inside my Spark Job, after doing the table bulk-loading stuff.

For that I added the following method and call it between the dataframe.save() and sparkContext.close() method in my Java Code:

```
private static void updatePhoenixTableStatistics(String phoenixTableName) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database..");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:my-server.net:2181:/hbase-unsecure");
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM SYSTEM.STATS WHERE physical_name='" + phoenixTableName + "'");
            System.out.println("Successfully deleted statistics data... Now refreshing it.");

            st.executeUpdate("UPDATE STATISTICS " + phoenixTableName + " ALL");
            System.out.println("Successfully refreshed statistics data.");

            st.close();
            conn.close();

            System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to update table statistics - Skipping this step!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The Problem is, that since I added this method I Always get the following exception at the end of my Spark Job:

```
Bulk-Load: DataFrame.save() completed - Import finished successfully!
Updating Table Statistics:
Connecting to database..
Creating statement...
Successfully deleted statistics data... Now refreshing it.
Successfully refreshed statistics data.
Connection closed.
Exception in thread "Thread-31" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-e5b01508-0f84-4702-9684-4f6ceac803f9/gk-journal-importer-phoenix-0.0.3h.jar (No such file or directory)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2794)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2646)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2518)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:1065)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:1119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1520)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:82)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:97)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigurationFactoryImpl$1.call(ConfigurationFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigurationFactoryImpl$1.call(ConfigurationFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:78)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.callWithoutPropagation(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:93)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigurationFactoryImpl.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver$1.run(PhoenixDriver.java:88)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spark-e5b01508-0f84-4702-9684-4f6ceac803f9/gk-journal-importer-phoenix-0.0.3h.jar (No such file or directory)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:69)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:99)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2693)
        ... 14 more
```

Does someone know About this Problem and can help? How the generally work with JDBC inside a Spark Job? Or is there another possibility for doing that?

I'm working on HDP 2.6.5 with Spark 2.3 and Phoenix 4.7 installed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem. The jar I exported included the phoenix-spark2 and phoenix-client dependencies and were included into my jar file.

I changed these dependencies (as they are already existing in my clusters HDP installation) to be of scope provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-spark2</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>                          <!-- this did it, now have to add --jar to spark-submit -->
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.phoenix</groupId>
    <artifactId>phoenix-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0.2.6.5.0-292</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>                          <!-- this did it, now have to add --jar to spark-submit -->
</dependency>
```

Now I start my Spark job with the **--jars** option and link these dependencies there. Now it works fine in **yarn-client** mode.

```
spark-submit --class spark.dataimport.SparkImportApp --master yarn --deploy-mode client --jars /usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-spark2.jar,/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/phoenix-client.jar hdfs:/user/test/gk-journal-importer-phoenix-0.0.3h.jar <some parameters for the main method>
```

PS: In **yarn-cluster** mode the application worked all the time (also with the fat-jar that included the dependencies).